# Formatting issue on community message

Tags: bug, status-completed

The CSS line-height on `#system-message`, which styles the community message, needs to be increased or removed:

[image]

Comment: I slightly altered it for now, until this bug can be fixed, since it looked very odd :)

Comment: Where did you alter it? I looked for a place to do that and didn't see it.

Comment: Had to click "Remove" or something next to the message before adding it again.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for editing. Looks much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I pushed a fix to dev. It will be in the next production build.

Comment: Thank you very much!